# Rails 4: condition on model.date.strftime("%u") never true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, ruby-on-rails-4, strftime

In my Rails 4 app, I have a `post` model with a custom `:date` attribute.

In the `post.rb` file, I defined the following method:

```
def test_days
    if self.date.strftime("%u") == 4
        "Message 1"
    elsif self.date.strftime("%u") == 5
        "Message 2"
    else
        "Message 3"
    end
end
```

Whichever date I assign to a post object, I always get "Message 3" displayed — even when I should get "Message 1" or "Message 2".

I tried Today.date.strftime("%u") and got 1 (which is the right answer, since we are Monday in my timezone).

So, it seems my condition, ie: `self.date.strftime("%u") == 4` or `self.date.strftime("%u") == 5` is never true.

But I can't figure out why.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strftime("%u")` returns a string. 2 potential solutions:

`if self.date.strftime("%u") == "4"`

or

`if self.date.wday == 4`

Comment: Awesome! I went with solution number 1, but glad to know there is a second option. Thank you very much for your help.